# Display issue in C with pointer and structur from excel values

Tags: c, excel, structure

I'm encountering an issue when i run my program. Indeed, i can't correctly display each fetched variables from my excel file (correctly encoded with UTF-8). This excel file only contains cities name. These names are stored in structures(Test here) which are in my pointer list named : "test_list". However, when i display these variables previously, they are correctly displayed.

See below my simplified program and the out :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Test Test;

const nbr_villes = 23;

struct Test
{
    char* nom;
};

Test *init_test(char *nom) {

    Test *test = malloc(sizeof(Test));
    test->nom = nom;

    return test;
}

void fill_test(Test **test_list)
{
    FILE *csv_file = fopen("villes.csv", "r");

    char line[1024];

    // remove header "Ville"
    fgets(line, 0, csv_file);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nbr_villes ; i++)
    {
        fgets(line, 1024, csv_file);
        char *tmp = strdup(line);
        printf("%s\n", tmp);
        test_list[i] = init_test(tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // 23 éléments dans liste de test
    Test **test_list = malloc(nbr_villes * sizeof(struct Test));
    fill_test(test_list);

    for (int i = 0; i < nbr_villes; i++){
        printf("%s\n",test_list[i]->nom);
    }
}
```

and the out :

```
(prints of tmp :)

ville

Amiens

Bayonne

Bordeaux

Bourges

Caen

Clermont-Ferrand

Dijon

Grenoble

Le-Mans

Lille

Lyon

Marseille

Metz

Montpellier

Nantes

Nice

Niort

Paris

Reims

Rennes

Strasbourg

Toulouse

(Errors are here : prints in the main loop :)

@f
@f
êf
êf
êf
êf
¿f
¿f
░f
░f
░f
░f
░f
Metz

░f
Rennes

Ïf
Niort

pf
hf
Rennes

Strasbourg

Toulouse
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    char *tmp = strdup(line);
    printf("%s\n", tmp);
    test_list[i] = init_test(tmp);
    free(tmp);
```

The `char *` memorized int *Test* themselves memorized in `test_list` are freed by *free(tmp)*

`test->nom = nom;` copy the pointer, the string is not duplicated, you need to do `test->nom = strdup(nom);` or just remove the `free(tmp);`

But for me the best way is to call `init_test(line)` (without duplication) and the *strdup* is made in `init_test` because it has to know a duplication must be done, not the caller

Comment: Merci effectivement durant la simplification du code j'ai enlevé une partie du code qui mettait  en avant de manière moins evidente la liaison entre la varaible et le "free".